# How to write a program in Python for printing a "string" at the end of a line in the file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

`input_file` contains: `Hi How are you`

Expected output is: `AHi How are youB`

Tried with the below program:

```
input = open("input_file",'r')
output = open("output_file",'w')

for line in input:
    newline = "A" + line + "B"
    output.write(newline)
input.close()
output.close()
```

I am getting the following output:

```
AHi How are you
B
```

Please suggest how to change the program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you read the `line` in from the `input` file, it really looks like:

```
"Hi How are you\n"
```

i.e. includes a newline character at the end of the line. Therefore after you add `'A'` and `'B'` it looks like:

```
"AHi How are you\nB"
              # ^ still has newline
```

and you see the line break in your output.

The minimal fix to remove this is to add [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove all whitespace (including newlines) from the start and end of the `line`:

```
newline = "A" + line.strip() + "B"
```

but I would recommend switching to more modern [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) too:

```
newline = "A{0}B".format(line.strip())
```

Comment: The docs you refer you say *The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace.* Does `\n` count as a whitespace then?

Comment: @TimCastelijns yes - try `assert "foo\n".strip() == "foo"`

Comment: Ah great, I didn't know that yet.